# How to group rows in into unique id

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have 1000+ rows shows like below

```
ID              V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
KCT00094653     0   0   0   0   0   1   0
KCT00094653     0   0   0   1   0   0   0
KCT00094653     0   0   0   0   0   0   1
KCT00094653     0   0   1   0   0   0   0
KCT00140855     0   0   0   0   1   0   0
KCT00140855     0   0   0   0   0   0   1
KCT00140855     0   0   0   0   0   1   0
KCT00140855     0   0   0   1   0   0   0
KCT00162123     0   1   0   0   0   0   0
KCT00162123     1   0   0   0   0   0   0
KCT00323882     0   0   0   0   0   1   0
KCT00323882     0   0   0   1   0   0   0
KCT00323882     0   0   0   0   0   0   1
KCT00323882     0   0   0   0   1   0   0
KCT00323882     0   1   0   0   0   0   0
 I trying to get all the 1 in a row for single Id
```

and the expected output is like below

```
ID          V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7
KCT00094653 0   0   1   1   0   1   1
KCT00140855 0   0   0   1   1   1   1
KCT00162123 1   1   0   0   0   0   0
KCT00323882 0   1   0   1   1   1   1
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(across(.fns = max))`

Comment: Maybe a bit more extended: `res <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(across(.cols = everything(), .fns = max) %>% ungroup()`